# How to use command line tool "unzip" to only grab a certain folder?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, unzip

I have a .jar file which can be opened with the Command line tool "unzip", which has this option called `-p` so you can grab certain files. But how do you do this with a folder? Here's what this jar file is structured like.

```
My.jar
|-folder
|   |-Content
|        |-My Files
|   |-First Folder
|        |-Second Folder
|             |-Files
|-image.png
|-foo.class
|-bar.class
```

The Folder "folder" that I want to grab also has a lot more files just than "My Files" and "Files".

The Command I tried: `unzip dir/to\ a\ folder/My.jar -d dir/to\ a/desired\ folder -p folder/ | image.png`

Without the other file: `unzip dir/to\ a\ folder/My.jar -d dir/to\ a/desired\ folder -p folder/`

I tried this with the `jar` command, and that seemed to work, but I specifically want to do this with `unzip`.

And the error I got is:

> caution: filename not matched:  -p
>   caution: filename not matched:  assets/,

Unzip Help Menu I have:
[image: Unzip on macOS 10.13.6]

Comment: Which `unzip` command are you using? The Info-Zip one seems to be the standard on Linux distributions. That does have a "-p" option but it doesn't do what you need. Can you provide more details about your unzip  please? Try running `unzip -h`.

Comment: I attached an image of the one that came with my mac, `unzip -h` isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good, that's just standard info-zip `unzip` you are running.

The `-p` option you are using doesn't do what you expect. Below is the man page for entry for `-p`.

```
   -p     extract files to pipe (stdout).  Nothing but the  file  data  is
          sent  to  stdout,  and  the files are always extracted in binary
          format, just as they are stored (no conversions).
```

Let's work though an example. First create a directory tree that is similar to yours

```
data
`-- folder
    `-- Content
        |-- FirstFolder
        |   `-- SecondFolder
        |       `-- Files
        |           |-- f1
        |           |-- f2
        |           `-- f3
        `-- MyFiles
            |-- a1
            |-- a2
            `-- a3
```

Stick that into a zip

```
$ zip -r try.zip data
$ unzip -l data.zip
Archive:  try.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  04-22-2020 08:59   data/
        0  04-22-2020 08:59   data/file1
        0  04-22-2020 08:59   data/file2
        0  04-22-2020 08:56   data/folder/
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/f2
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/f1
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/f3
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/MyFiles/
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/MyFiles/a3
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/MyFiles/a1
        0  04-22-2020 08:57   data/folder/Content/MyFiles/a2
        0  04-22-2020 08:59   data/file3
---------                     -------
        0                     16 files
```

If you want to extract only the `folder` subtree, you need to give `unzip` a wildcard that matches the subtree. In this instance `data/folder/*` will do the trick.

```
$ unzip -d output try.zip 'data/folder/*' 
Archive:  try.zip
   creating: output/data/folder/
   creating: output/data/folder/Content/
   creating: output/data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/
   creating: output/data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/
   creating: output/data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/
 extracting: output/data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/f2  
 extracting: output/data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/f1  
 extracting: output/data/folder/Content/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/Files/f3  
   creating: output/data/folder/Content/MyFiles/
 extracting: output/data/folder/Content/MyFiles/a3  
 extracting: output/data/folder/Content/MyFiles/a1  
 extracting: output/data/folder/Content/MyFiles/a2
```